# Windows Forms アプリケーションで、ボタン等のフォントにSegoe UIが指定できない

Tags: windows, c#, visual-studio

VisualStudioを利用したWindows Forms アプリケーションで、
フォーム上にボタンなどコントロールを配置しております。

ボタンやテキストボックスのプロパティにてテキストのフォントへSegoe UI を指定したいのですが、
フォント選択ダイアログのフォントリストにSegoe UI が存在せず選択できません。
＃ Segoe Marker、Segoe UI Emoji、Segoe UI Symbol、Segoe WP は、リスト上に出ています。

Segoe UIは、指定不可能なのでしょうか。
また、指定不可能な理由をご存知でしたらご教授ください。

ちなみに、Excelなどのアプリケーションでは、Segoe UIは指定可能です。
＃ つまりSegoe UIフォント自体はインストールされている。

[環境]
OS: Windows 8 64bit 日本語版
開発環境 : Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最近のWindowsは表示言語に基づいて、フォントを表示する・表示しないという振る舞いを実装しています。
フォント選択ダイアログで表示されない場合は、C:\Windows\Fonts を開いていただいて、該当のフォントを探していただき、「表示」をクリックしてください。

Comment: ご教授いただいた方法にて、Segoe UI フォントが指定できました。
ご回答ありがとうございました。